# Binding DataGrid.SelectedItem to the Displayed Member of a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that contains a list of `People`, each of which have a supervisor associated with them. All the possible `Supervisors` are listed in a `ComboBox` below the `DataGrid`.

What I would like to happen is that when the user chooses a `Person` in the `DataGrid`, the appropriate `Supervisor` is automatically selected from the `ComboBox`.

I have tried using things like;

`personSupervisorComboBox.SelectedItem = selectedPerson.SupervisorName;`

and

`personSupervisorComboBox.DisplayMemberPath= selectedPerson.SupervisorName;`

but as of yet nothing has worked in selecting the correct member from the `ComboBox`. Is there a way I can bind the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` so that when the user chooses a `Person` from the `DataGrid` their supervisor is correctly displayed in the `ComboBox`?

EDIT:

XAML

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" x:Name="personSupervisorComboBox" Margin="5" FontSize="14" DisplayMemberPath="FullName" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectedValue="ID"/>
```

Code-Behind (that I've tried so far)

```
personSupervisorComboBox.Text = selectedPerson.SupervisorName;
```

Comment: How do you set the ItemsSource of the ComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably after a solution involving a [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx) - this is a special collection container which tracks the current item so that it can be shared between multiple items.
Note the special binding syntax in the ComboBox below: the use of "/" specifies that this binding is relative to the 'CurrentItem' of the Collection View. That is to say it is  binding to the supervisor of the current selected item in the collectionViewSource, which is synchronized with the currently selected item in the datagrid

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvsPeople" Source="{Binding whereMyPeopleAre}" />
</Window.Resources>

<!-- ... -->

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsPeople}}" SelectedItem="{Binding /Supervisor, Source={StaticResource cvsPeople}}"  />

<!-- ... -->

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={staticResource cvsPeople}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

[Disclaimer: I haven't compiled/tested this snippet, please account for Typos]